# Masks bits of array members

Tags: c, arrays, embedded, bit-manipulation, flags

Can you direct me where is my problem here? I am trying to test values of an array.

Every value presents 16 bits (flags) and I need to check if the flag is set or not.

My current output is shown below and also the expected output.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    unsigned short value[1];
    unsigned int bitCheck(unsigned int mask, int pin);
    unsigned short mask;

int main(void){
    value[0]=0;
    value[1]=4095;


    int pin0 = 0;
    int pin1 = 1;

    unsigned int bit0= bitCheck( mask, pin0);
    unsigned int bit1= bitCheck( mask, pin1);


  for (int i =0;i<=1; i++)
{
    mask=value[i];
   printf("Mask = %d ==>>\n", mask);

   if ( bit0 == 1 ){
      printf("Pin %d is Set\n", pin0);
   }else{
      printf("Pin %d is not Set\n", pin0);
   }

    if ( bit1 == 1 ){
      printf("Pin %d is Set\n", pin1);
   }else{
      printf("Pin %d is not Set\n", pin1);
   }

   printf("\n"); 
}

}

unsigned int bitCheck(unsigned int mask, int bit){
   if ( (mask >> bit ) & 1){
      return 1;
   }else{
      return 0;
   }
}
```

My output is:

```
Mask = 0 ==>>
Pin 0 is not Set
Pin 1 is not Set

Mask = 4095 ==>>
Pin 0 is not Set
Pin 1 is not Set
```

and it must be:

```
Mask = 0 ==>>
Pin 0 is not Set
Pin 1 is not Set

Mask = 4095 ==>>
Pin 0 is Set
Pin 1 is Set
```

Comment: Umm, you didn't set `mask` originally, so it remains 0. Then later in the loop you're not setting `pin` variables. I am not sure *why* you think this should give any other results...

Comment: Or, like my friend put it, perhaps there wasn't enough cosmic radiation to flip the bits in 0s to 1s. It might help if you produce an actual [mcve], with the emphasis on the word minimal.

Comment: value[0]=0;
value[1]=4095;


   mask=value[i];

       @AnttiHaapala

Comment: Please ident your code properly in the future. It is totally unreadable.

Comment: @MhdBanat yes, that's why it prints `4095` the second time... where are you re-setting the `pinN` then?

Comment: The [mcve] means that you will have to remove the non-essential parts of the code ... in *your* program - then run it. The 12-time repetition is completely unnecessary to reproduce the problem. Had you done this, the answer would have been clear right away.

Comment: Thank you all for correcting me, @AnttiHaapala, @ Nikolai Shalakin.

It's now minimal, complete, verifiable example.

What is my problem ?

Comment: You just need `printf` for one bit... and the `for` loop can go too... just set the value that you need...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is unnecessarily complex and through it's complexity, hides a **blatant** logical error. You're doing your calls to `bitCheck(mask, ...)` **before** you ever assign a value to `mask`.

Change this:

```
    unsigned int bit0= bitCheck( mask, pin0);
    unsigned int bit1= bitCheck( mask, pin1);


  for (int i =0;i<=1; i++)
{
    mask=value[i];
   printf("Mask = %d ==>>\n", mask);
```

to this:

```
  for (int i =0;i<=1; i++)
{
    mask=value[i];

    unsigned int bit0= bitCheck( mask, pin0);
    unsigned int bit1= bitCheck( mask, pin1);

   printf("Mask = %d ==>>\n", mask);
```

---

That said, here's a **sane** way to do all this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BIT(n, v) (!!((v) & (1U << (n))))

int main(void)
{
    unsigned short values[] = {0, 4095};
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        printf("value: %hu\n", values[i]);
        for (int bit = 0; bit < 16; ++bit)
        {
            printf( BIT(bit, values[i]) ?
                    "bit %d is set\n" :
                    "bit %d is not set\n", bit);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For one reason why your approach isn't considered sane, read about the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Writing 16 times the same code is a simple example of violating this principle -> you need a loop instead.

Comment: On 16-bit arches, without `U` suffix even this would shift to the sign bit and therefore UB.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala yes, for 16bit `int` you're correct of course. I changed the code.